# random choice of multiple lists but delete element chosen

Tags: random

I want to make a function which takes lists as an input and outputs one element out of one of the list with uniform probability (if for example we have 2 lists, one with 7 and one with 3 elements, each element should have chance 1/10 to be picked) and removes that element from the list it was chosen from. This should work for 1,2 or 4 lists. I wouldn't mind creating 3 different functions for this. For 2 lists this would work:

```
randChoice[a_, b_] := 
  Module[{ran = RandomInteger[{1, Length[a] + Length[b]}], pos, ret},
   If[ran <= Length[a], ret = a[[ran]]; a = Delete[a, ran], 
    pos = ran - Length[a]; ret = b[[pos]]; b = Delete[b, pos]];
   Return[ret];
   ];
SetAttributes[randChoice, HoldAll]
```

Example input:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b = {1, 2, 3};
randChoice[a, b]
a
b
```

Is there a neater way to do this? It should be as fast as possible of course and should work for empty lists as well (though at least one list isn't empty).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[deleteRandom]
SetAttributes[deleteRandom, HoldAll]

deleteRandom[a : {__}] := Module[
  {pos = RandomChoice@Position[a, _, {2}, Heads -> False]}, 
  a = Delete[a, pos]; 
  pos]
```

***Examples:***

```
{a, b, c} = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {x, y, z, w}};

deleteRandom[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {1, 1}
> ```

```
{a, b, c}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {x, y, z, w}}
> ```

```
deleteRandom[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
>  {3, 2}
> ```

```
{a, b, c}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {x, z, w}}
> ```

```
{a, b, c, d, e} = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {}, {1, 2, 3}, {}, {x, y, z, w}};
tot = Total[Length /@ {a, b, c, d, e}];

SeedRandom[1]
Grid[Prepend[{"", a, b, c, d, e}][{#, ## & @@ #2} & @@@ 
   Table[{deleteRandom[{a, b, c, d, e}], {a, b, c, d, e}}, tot]], 
 Dividers -> {{False, Red}, {False, Red}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** A variation that returns the deleted element:

```
ClearAll[deleteRandom2]
SetAttributes[deleteRandom2, HoldAll]

deleteRandom2[a : {__}] := Module[{b = a, 
   pos = RandomChoice@Position[a, _, {2}, Heads -> False]}, 
   a = Delete[a, pos];
   b[[## & @@ pos]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
{a, b, c, d, e} = {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {}, {c1, c2, c3}, {}, {e1, e2, e3, e4}};
tot = Total[Length /@ {a, b, c, d, e}];

SeedRandom[1]
Grid[Prepend[{"", a, b, c, d, e}][{#, ## & @@ #2} & @@@ 
   Table[{deleteRandom2[{a, b, c, d, e}], {a, b, c, d, e}}, tot]], 
 Dividers -> {{False, Red}, {False, Red}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the code yet, but it works perfectly and is fast! I want to return the value of the removed element, not the position. I tried ```deleteRandom[a : {__}] := 
 Module[{pos = RandomChoice@Position[a, _, {2}, Heads -> False], ret},
   ret = a[[Sequence @@ pos]]; a = Delete[a, pos]; ret]``` but this is a bit slower. Is it possible to do this a little faster? Maybe as fast as if one returns the position?

Comment: @PeterMüller, please see the update.

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks a lot!!! This is super fast :) Perfect!!! Thanks!!! I now even believe to understand the code! Really can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
ClearAll @ randChoice;
randChoice[lists__] := Module[
    {
        choice = RandomChoice[
            (*make a table of all the list positions*)
            Flatten[
                Table[Thread[{n, Range[Length[Part[{lists}, n]]]}],
                    {n, Length @ {lists}}
                ],
                1
            ]
        ],
        res
    },
    res = Extract[{lists}, choice];
    {lists} = ReplacePart[{lists}, choice -> Nothing];
    res
];
SetAttributes[randChoice, HoldAll]
```

You can pass in any number of lists:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b = {1, 2, 3};
c = {"x", "y", "z"};

randChoice[a, b, c]
{a, b, c}
(* "x" *)
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {"y", "z"}} *)

randChoice[a, b, c]
{a, b, c}
(* 1 *)
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3}, {"y", "z"}} *)

randChoice[a, b, c]
{a, b, c}
(* "y" *)
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3}, {"z"}} *)
```